# Lea instruction on datasegment

Tags: ida, disassembly

I wrote simple program(was built in release mode(x86)) to practise re skills but I can not understand one part of it.

C++ program:

```
int doSub(int a, int b) 
{
    int result = a + b;
    result -= 2;
    return result;
}

int doSum(int a, int b)
{
    int result = a + b;
    result += 2;
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{      
    int wynik = 0;
    int liczbaA = atoi(argv[1]);
    int liczbaB = atoi(argv[2]);

    if (liczbaA > 3)
    {
        wynik = doSum(liczbaA, liczbaB);
    }
    else
    {
        wynik = doSub(liczbaA, liczbaB);
    }

    std::cout << "Result" << wynik;
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

And my question is: what is happening here?

```
lea     ecx, ds:0FFFFFFFEh[ecx*4] ; ??
```

I supposed to see here two instructions like sub/add. Can someone explain me how it's handled here operation +2 and -2?

@edit

```
loc_401052:
mov     edi, [ebp+argv]
push    dword ptr [edi+4] ; Str
call    ds:__imp__atoi
add     esp, 4
mov     ebx, eax
push    dword ptr [edi+8] ; Str
call    ds:__imp__atoi
xor     ecx, ecx
add     esp, 4
add     eax, ebx
mov     edx, offset aResult ; "Result"
cmp     ebx, 3
setnle  cl
lea     ecx, ds:0FFFFFFFEh[ecx*4]
add     eax, ecx
push    eax
push    ecx
mov     ecx, ds:__imp_?cout@std@@3V?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@A ; std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> std::cout
call    std__operator___std__char_traits_char___
add     esp, 4
mov     ecx, eax
call    ds:__imp_??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV01@H@Z ; std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator<<(int)
pop     edi
xor     eax, eax
pop     ebx
mov     esp, ebp
pop     ebp
retn
main endp
```

Comment: don't put assembly as an image. Please put some effort and use text. It's easier for everyone

Comment: sorry for that, when I will come back home, I will change it

Comment: A suggestion for future explorations: submit your code at [Godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/) where you can see what different compilers produce for the same code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0FFFFFFFEh` is `-2` in decimal format

ecx= is 1 if liczbaA is more than 3 and 0 otherwise

instruction LEA (load effective address) can do special arithmetic operation: `a + b*X + Y` where `a` and `b` are registers, `Y` is constant and `X` is 1, 2, 4 or 8.

In your case you calculate:
`-2+4*ecx` or `-2+4*(liczbaA>3)`

if liczbaA is more than 3 then result is 2 if less then it is -2

Comment: It make sense. Two questions from my side: 1. "-2 + 4*ecx", is there always add operator(between number and register)? 2. Does "ds:" have special meaning here? or on (x86) can I ignore it?

Answer (score 2):

Release mode optimises. if you want to see simple unoptimised asm blow-by-blow - turn off all optimisations or compile your code in debug mode (not sure the latter will work tho).

The whole segment from

```
cmp ebx,3
```

to

```
add eax, ecx
```

looks like the equivalent of the original *if* with your two functions inlined and the condition flattened into a series of arithmetic operations.

Comment: A minor note: even when *not* specifying full optimization, a lot of current compilers already optimize as much as possible in the initial compiling run. Gone are the days you could quite literally "read" the translation of one C instruction in a coherent series of ASM statements.